# I am unable to get the option value to add to cart at checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using plugins from Modern Tribe called Events Calendar and Event Tickets+ which is integrates with woo-commerce.

When booking an event, the user is asked to input the attendees details. I want to add to the end of the form the option for the user to have their ticket sent in the post. They will be presented with a radio option to include postage and packing.

I have added the file I am targeting to my child theme and added the code successfully to produce the radio button option. However, the code I have written to have the value added to the cart does not work.

*I should add, that when the user selects an event, they then get taken to Cart. They are then asked for their attendee details,where I have my radio option. They then get taken to checkout, so it is here that the fee needs to be added. I have added this paragraph to my initial description, in case it is relevant.*

Can anyone help please?

```
function ashweb_checkout_radio_choice() {

    $chosen = WC()->session->get('radio_chosen');
    $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? WC()->checkout->get_value('radio_choice') : $chosen;
    $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? 'no_option' : $chosen;

    $args = array(
        'type' => 'radio',
        'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
        'options' => array(
            'no_option' => 'No Option',
            'option_1' => 'Option 1 ($1.65)',
        ),
        'default' => $chosen
    );

    echo '<div id="checkout-radio">';
    echo '<h3>Add Postage and Packing!</h3>';
    woocommerce_form_field( 'radio_choice', $args, $chosen );
    echo '</div>';
}

ashweb_checkout_radio_choice();

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'ashweb_checkout_radio_choice_fee', 20, 1 );

function ashweb_checkout_radio_choice_fee( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    $radio = WC()->session->get( 'radio_chosen' );

    if ( "option_1" == $radio ) {
        $fee = 1.65;
    }

    $cart->add_fee( __('Option Fee', 'woocommerce'), $fee );
}
```

Comment: @Nasser - As far as I can tell, the code contains an equal amount of opening and closing brackets.

Comment: I cannot see any issues with the brackets

Comment: *I should add, that when the user selects an event, they then get taken to Cart. They are then asked for their attendee details,where I have my radio option. They then get taken to checkout, so it is here that the fee needs to be added. I have added this paragraph to my initial description, in case it is relevant.*